# NodeJS/Express: How can I submit a form by associating multiple input text fields with each of its own file upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a NodeJS/Express app where I have to make a form submission after user's input.

There could be one or a million `input type text` fields and that depends on the user. Each of those text fields will have its own `input type file` allowing the user the choice to upload a file.

Suppose a user decides to submit 3 pieces of data so he chooses 3 text fields: `textField1, textFieldd2, and textField3`. Each of these text fields will have its own file upload field: `fileFieldFortext1, fileFieldFortext2, and fileFieldFortext3`. Now whether he uploads a file or leaves it empty, is totally upto him.

Scenario 1: When he decides to upload files for all 3 of the text fields:

```
<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />

<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />

<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />

const textContent = req.body.textContent;
const fileData = req.files.fileInput;
 
textContent output: an array of all the texts. ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
fileData output: an array of objects of all the file data. [ {'fileFortext1'}, {'fileFortext2'}, {'fileFortext3'} ]
```

I can easily associate them based on their `index`. It works perfectly. But the issue arises in Scenario 2.

Scenario 2: When he decides not to upload one or two files:

```
<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" /> // leaves it empty

<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />

<input type="text" name="textContent" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />

const textContent = req.body.textContent;
const fileData = req.files.fileInput;

textContent output: an array of all the texts. ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
fileData output: an array of objects of all the file data. [ {'fileFortext2'}, {'fileFortext3'} ].
```

Now I'm not able to associate them based on index value as the user didn't upload any file for the first one.

How can I get an output like this in my backend: `[ {}, {'fileFortext2'}, {'fileFortext3'} ]` with the first one as empty object?

or

How can I associate each text fields with its own file upload input?

Am I approaching it in a wrong way?

Please note that I'm not using AJAX to submit the form. It is a direct submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, with the `mutler` package `upload.any()` middleware on the server side. You may want to adapt it to your particular setup. Note it seems you can get away with naming the matching `text` and `file` `inputs` with the same `name` for convenience since these are different content types.

```
<input type="text" name="1" />
<input type="file" name="1" />

<input type="text" name="2" />
// No file here

<input type="text" name="3" />
<input type="file" name="3" />
```

This is what you would get on the server-side:

```
req.body = { '1': 'text1 value', '2': 'text2 value', '3': 'text3 value' }
req.files = [
    { fieldname: '1', /* Other properties */ },
    { fieldname: '3', /* Other properties */ }
]
```

And then you can map the texts and files however you want based on the input name:

```
var combined = Object.keys(req.body).map(function (key) {
    let fileIndex = req.files.findIndex(file => file.fieldname == key);
    return { text: req.body[key], file: fileIndex >= 0 ? req.files[fileIndex] : undefined }
})

console.log(combined)

//console output
[
  { text: 'text1 value', file: { fieldname: '1', /* Other properties */ } },
  { text: 'text2 value', file: undefined },
  { text: 'text3 value', file: { fieldname: '3', /* Other properties */ } }
]
```

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for your time. I've used Multer before. But it seemed too complicated. 
 But I'll check it again. About the solution you provided, I could do that if only there were an exact number of fields and I hardcoded the ```name``` values. But its not possible to know whether the user wants to submit one text field with its file or a thousand.

Comment: Ok. Note though you would not actually need to know the exact number of fields in advance, but you would need to be able to generate the inputs names dynamically on the client.

Comment: Bro. thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. Though I had to tweak a little but it worked. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the fields in pre-render, you can work with array of fields in express:

```
const textFields = ["textField1", "textField2", "textField3"];
```

Use that array to generate the fields to render the form:

```
<input type="text" name="textContent[textField1]" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[textField1]" />

<input type="text" name="textContent[textFieldd2]" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[textFieldd2]" />

<input type="text" name="textContent[textField3]" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[textField3]" />
```

And then, when you receive the submit data form the in Express, use the same array in a loop, for you get the values this way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < textFields.length; i += 1) {
  console.log('INPUT VALUE: textContent ${textFields[i]}:>> ', req.body.textContent[textFields[i]]);
  if(textFields[i] in req.body.fileInput){
    console.log('FILE VALUE: fileInput ${textFields[i]}:>> ', req.body.fileInput[textFields[i]]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your time. Can you please tell me what you meant by knowing the fields in  pre-render? Basically the form has 1 text field and its one file upload by default. There's a button which appends a text field and a file upload. The user can add any number they want. Then he fills the data and submits.

Comment: My solution not works in this scenario, sorry.